# asp.net parameter update reports 1 row updated but no data in table added

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, t-sql

I am getting an incorrect repsonse after an update to a table. In my RowUpdating event I have the following code which builds an Update Parameter to call an SP to update a table. I must be doing something wrong but everything runs fine. My rowsAffected variable reports 1 after the update, but the table never gets the data.

Here is the relevant code behind in RowUpdating event. The values are correctly populated in the parameters as well.

```
itemDataSource.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("myConnString").ToString()

itemDataSource.UpdateCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure
itemDataSource.UpdateCommand = "usp_updatePTT"                 ' Call stored procedure

    'Establishes value of Primary key and String sent to SP 
    itemDataSource.UpdateParameters.Add("ID", updateKey)
    itemDataSource.UpdateParameters.Add("lang_String", updateString)

    Dim rowsAffected As Integer = 0
    rowsAffected = itemDataSource.Update()

    GridView4.DataBind()
```

and here is the SP....

```
@ID int,
@lang_String nvarchar(1000)

AS
    /* SET NOCOUNT ON */

BEGIN
   UPDATE       tblLangROOTptt
   SET                lang_String = @lang_String
   WHERE        (ID = @ID)
END

RETURN
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated...
thanks,

UPDATE: I found a solution that is working. On the original DataSource for the update command I needed to add the following....

```
UpdateCommand="EXEC usp_updatePTTrootString @ID=@original_ID, @lang_String=@lang_string" >
```

This in essence allows the original data source to call the SP. Note: that the command type needs to stay as TEXT not Stored Procedure as one might think.

Comment: @marc11h Which table the one in your database or the one that you databind to?

Comment: the table is in the DB. I have tried executenonquery it didn't work either.

Comment: do you have different dev and production tables for this project... you may be referencing a different database with that connection string.

Comment: No I am on one machine and conn string is pointing to correct db. There is no prodcution deployment as of yet.

Comment: @marc11h Have you tried to do the stored procedure from a database IDE?? I mean have you tried to do it straight from sql commands

Comment: Yes I used the Query builder and provided values, executes fine.

Comment: @marc11h can you try to execute teh stored procedure from your query builder.... trying to eleminate the sproc as the problem

Comment: A stored procedure will always return a 1 when you use rowsAffected because the query gets executed on the SQL Server as:

    `DECLARE @return_value int

    EXEC @return_value = [usp_UpdatePPT]
  @ID = 123,
        @lang_string = ''`

What type is your itemDataSource?  Are you using a DataSet or an ADO.NET Object like SqlCommand?

Comment: RowsAffected initially returned -1 until I changed the variable type in SP from varchar to nvarchar to match table def.    itemDataSource is  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="itemDataSource" runat="server"></asp:SqlDataSource> ...............    query executes in mgmt studio just fine as well.

Comment: Solution is in the original post. Look for the UPDATE: tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: I found a solution that is working. On the original DataSource for the update command I needed to add the following....

```
UpdateCommand="EXEC usp_updatePTTrootString @ID=@original_ID, @lang_String=@lang_string" >
```

This in essence allows the original data source to call the SP. Note: that the command type needs to stay as TEXT not Stored Procedure as one might think.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are redatabinding the table with the preupdated table values. You might have to recall the select statement that gets the values of the data sent to the datagrid.

Comment: That may be true, but my main concern at the moment is getting the data into the DB table, recalling select stmt won't do any good if the data nevers gets written back to the DB table. FYI, I not so cercerned with Gridview at the moment, just need to get the DB updated.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you are updating the table with a value that it already has?

Comment: Is the ID field a string?  If so, it's possible trailing spaces are preventing the correct row from being found.  The command will still return as a success even if no records are updated.

Comment: One last guess:  Do you have two databases?  Are you updating one and looking in another?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a couple of problems all of them related to doing too much in the row_updated method.

If you are in row_Updated, that means that your SQL data source is already in the process of being updated, so then you are calling a separate update before the previous set of updates completes (you're only in the row and I'm assuming there are multiple rows).

Then, you are binding the gridview that is tied to the datasource before you re-update the DataSource.

I would suggest using a separate DataSource to do your secondary update.  For example:

```
Sub MyGridView_RowUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs)
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("myConnString").ToString())
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("usp_updatePPT")
    cmd.Connection = conn
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", updateKey)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lang_string", updateString)
    Try
        conn.Open()
        Dim rdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        dt.Load(rdr, LoadOption.Upsert)
        conn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        If conn.State > 0 Then
            conn.Close()
        End If
        'TODO: Your error handling logic here
    End Try
End Sub
```

As for updating the GridView again, just do a page refresh (unless you want to significantly alter the flow of your code-behind).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'll try this routine. Okay quick update though. Gridview4 is a second grid so I could try and see the update, not the grid that actually produced the query, so in essence I am using a different data source. I dont have any code in the RowUpdated event. I am working in the RowUpdating event not the RowUpdated event.